# De-flattern surface so that it's affected by subdivision

Tags: modeling

[image: The surfaces are the ones at the bottom]

[image]

Hi,

I'm new to modelling, and deleted some verticies of my model that I have a subdivided modifer on. The deleted verticies left an empty polygon which I filled by selecting perimeter verticies and hitting `F`

This has left me with a surface that isn't subdividing like the others around. What can I do to make it behave like a normal surface?

Tested a few things so I can't just `Ctrl` + `Z` unfortunately.

Comment: share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 2):

If all holes in the mesh are filled, make sure you have no duplicate vertices or flipped normals causing issues for the *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

1. Select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Hit <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance*.
3. With everything still selected, recalculate the normals with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

**//EDIT:** If there is one normal showing in the center of the "two" faces, this means it is just one big face instead of two with a single unconnected edge between those middle vertices.

So this means the four corner vertices of the large face are connected to build one face and the two vertices in the middle are connected to build one edge.

1. First you have to get rid of the face and the edge: select the large face, press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Faces*.
2. The edge remains. Select it, then press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Edges*.
3. Now select four vertices (or three edges) connected to each other to create a new (small) face with <kbd>F</kbd>. Do not select the four outmost vertices of the hole.
4. Now a smaller hole remains. Select the surrounding vertices and hit <kbd>F</kbd> again to fill this hole, too.

Now there should be two normals showing, one in the center of the left face, one in the center of the right face. No normal on the edge between them.

Comment: Duplicate vertices or flipped normals would produce a result like in picture 4 and 5 of my answer. here the issue is caused by a third quad face located behind the two visible one and sharing some of the same vertices

Comment: @ponsdeleon Actually what puzzled me is that with testing on a similar object and having overlapping faces like you are showing in pic 1 and 2, the resulting geometry looks like pic 4 in my Blender, the four corner vertices sharp instead of rounded like you show. So I wasn't sure if there is something like that going on... but since I didn't have the original file I couldn't inspect it further. My recreation with overlapping faces didn't look like the original in the question.

Comment: I tried this and it seemed to make no difference visually, or when I visualise the normals. There are other normals which I edited my post with another photo. Any further suggestions?

Comment: @BlueTurtle Regarding the comment under the other answer that you only see one centered normal instead of three, I've edited my answer.

Comment: I applied your edit and got the two normals, but the mesh still doesn't subdivide properly. Are there more steps to follow? Recalculating makes the two new normals disappear

Comment: @BlueTurtle Well, duplicated faces, incorrect normals, wrong faces are mostly all which come to my mind now. Maybe it would have been much easier and quicker to solve if you simply uploaded the file to your question as Harry suggested in his comment below there.

Comment: I figured it out; I saw on a tutorial that someone was using H to get rid of items, but I know now that's just hiding it and not actually deleting it. Once I unhid and deleted all those items - the normals you can see in the second photo - it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to faces overlapping.

Here is a recreation of the issue, I have already merged vertices by distance and recalculated the normals but the result is still of:[image]

as you can see I am able to select another face on the same place (sometimes you have to enter wireframe view to be able to select it as it is behind the other face)

[image]
Here we have a better view as I have enabled the normal visualization (the normals orientation is represented by the cyan line): as you can see we have 3 normals, which means 3 faces where we expect to have two faces
[image]
Delete the biggest face to solve the problem

They are two other cases where you could have an hard edge around some faces where you would expect something smother thanks to subdivision surface. Here I have recreated them.

1. wrong face orientation (we can't see the normal direction because it is facing the inside of the mesh):
   [image]
2. vertices really close to each other (here there is an inset on a really small distance):
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your breakdown. I selected all, merge by distance, then recalculated normals. That didn't make any visual difference. I enabled the normal visualisation, and I have one vertical line in the centre of the two faces, not three.  There are other normals which I edited my post with another photo.  Any further suggestions?